# Using grit with Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, grit

When I use `rails c`, I could type `repo = Grit::Repo.name("/path/path")` and there is no error.

But when I type these in my rails controller, there is a error message showing: `uninitialized constant AaaController::Grit` , and if I add `require 'grit'` , it says `no such file to load -- grit`.

I am sure that I have added `gem 'grit'` to my Gemfile and did `bundle install`.

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `::Grit`. In 1.9, constant lookup is a bit different.

Comment: You are right, but i also forget restart server when i do bundle install. Thanks!